# TypeError '2019' is not thenable

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I wanted to create a cucumber test step with protractor,but I got in the expect step the '2019' is not thenable.
Here is my source code:

```
        this.Then(/^I check that the calculated year from the current month\(if current month >= 6 ==> current year = current year \+ 2,else current year = current year \+ 1\)$/,function(callback) {

            var actualDate=new Date();
            var actualYear=actualDate.getFullYear();
            var actualMonth=actualDate.getMonth()+1;
            //expect(targetAmountPO.getYesInflationLabel().isDisplayed()).eventually.to.equal(true).then(callback);
            targetAmountPO.getYesInflationLabel().isDisplayed().then(function() {
                targetAmountPO.getYesInflationCorrectionAnswer().isSelected().then(function(){
                    targetAmountPO.getYesInflationLabel().getAttribute("outerText").then(function(text,callback){
                        //console.log(text);
                        var splittedString=text.split(":");
                        //console.log(splittedString[1]);
                        if(actualMonth>=6)
                        {
                            actualYear+=2;
                            var yearString=actualYear.toString();
                            console.log(yearString);
                             expect(yearString).to.eventually.contain(splittedString[1]).and.notify(callback);

                            //console.log(actualYear);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                             expect(actualYear+1).to.include(splittedString[1]).and.notify(callback);

                        }

                })

                })

            })


        })
```

At the expect(yearString).to.eventually.contain(splittedString[1]).and.notify(callback);

I got the '2019' is not thenable.
The yearString is 2019 is good.
But why is not thenable?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've properly handled the promise returned by `getAttribute("outerText")` the values in `yearString` and `splittedString` are just actual values and not promises so you can just use a chai assertion and not a chai as promised assertion like

```
expect(yearString).to.contain(splittedString[1])
callback()
```

and you'll be able to test that to ensure its not calling back before the assertion actually does the check

Comment: Thanks Ross.
I must understand promise,beacuse I am JAVA developer but I got AngularJS E2E test.